# How do I prevent duplicate entries in my Access database?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am a first time coder with VBA and I am creating a database for data entry at a Psych Lab I work at. Currently the database is created, but I want to prevent duplicate entries from being put into the database (namely by have a code look for the participant number right after it is entered). I have been trying to fix this code for quite a while and I just recently hit a wall. It displays the correct error message when I enter the participant number, however it says that every number has been entered already (even though they actually haven't). Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Participant_Number_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim Participant_Number As Integer

    Dim StLinkCriteria As Integer

    If (Not IsNull(DLookup("[Participant_Number]", "Entry Log", "[Participant_Number] ='" & Me.Participant_Number.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Participant Number has already been entered in the database."
    Cancel = True
    Me.Participant_Number.Undo
    End If

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have never used VBA before and I am self-teaching how to code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `Participant_Number` field is a `number`. You shouldn't enclose the criteria with single-quotes `'`, these are used with fields of `text` type. Try changing the criteria field from

> `"[Participant_Number] ='" & Me.Participant_Number.Value & "'"))) Then`

into

```
"[Participant_Number] = " & Me.Participant_Number.Value))) Then
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this did not fix the problem. I can get the error message to appear, but it appears for every number I enter regardless of whether or not it has already been entered.

Comment: @BreannaWallbaum this syntax is correct. You should check your data (are you sure the numbers were *already entered*? ), also check the field names and table names.

Comment: I am positive that the field names and table names are correct. I have already checked them. The numbers were not already entered and that is the problem. I would know because I just entered arbitrary data to test the database and have only entered 2 sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have not used VBA you may try to do this by opening the table in Design view. This method is easy and a good choice. You may have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prevent-duplicate-values-in-a-field-b5eaace7-6161-4edc-bb90-39d1a1bc5576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: I have already done that, however I need the user to get an error message saying that it has already been entered. Also, the way that I am setting up the database for entry will not give the raters access to the ribbons at the top of the screen. All they will do is hit enter to be taken to the next form (so the index option will not work). Thank you for the help, though.

Comment: is there a way to make an error message appear when say the raters hit the next button?